# Can asynchronous operations be used with `progress` on OperationQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, progress, operation, operationqueue

Starting in iOS13, one can monitor the progress of an `OperationQueue` using the `progress` property. The documentation states that only operations that do not override `start()` count when tracking progress. However, asynchronous operations **must** override `start()` and not call `super()` according to the documentation.

Does this mean `asynchronous` operations and `progress` are mutually exclusive (i.e. only synchronous operations can be used with progress)? This seems like a massive limitation if this is the case.

In my own project, I removed my override of `start()` and everything *appears* to work okay (e.g. dependencies are only started when `isFinished` is set to `true` on the dependent operation internally in my async operation base class). BUT, this seems risky since `Operation` explicitly states to override `start()`.

Thoughts?

Documentaiton references:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/3172535-progress

> By default, OperationQueue doesn’t report progress until totalUnitCount is set. When totalUnitCount is set, the queue begins reporting progress. Each operation in the queue contributes one unit of completion to the overall progress of the queue for operations that are finished by the end of main(). Operations that override start() and don’t invoke super don’t contribute to the queue’s progress.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1416837-start

> If you are implementing a concurrent operation, you must override this method and use it to initiate your operation. Your custom implementation must not call super at any time. In addition to configuring the execution environment for your task, your implementation of this method must also track the state of the operation and provide appropriate state transitions.

Update: I ended up ditching my `AysncOperation` for a simple `SyncOperation` that waits until `finish()` is called (using a semaphore).

```
/// A synchronous operation that automatically waits until `finish()` is called.
open class SyncOperation: Operation {

    private let waiter = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    /// Calls `work()` and waits until `finish()` is called.
    public final override func main() {
        work()
        waiter.wait()
    }

    /// The work of the operation. Subclasses must override this function and call `finish()` when their work is done.
    open func work() {
        preconditionFailure("Subclasses must override `work()` and call `finish()`")
    }

    /// Finishes the operation.
    ///
    /// The work of the operation must be completed when called. Failing to call `finish()` is a programmer error.
    final public func finish() {
        waiter.signal()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining two different but related concepts; asynchronous and concurrency.

An `OperationQueue` always dispatches `Operations` onto a separate thread so you do not need to make them explicitly make them asynchronous and there is no need to override `start()`.  You should ensure that your `main()` does not return until the operation is complete. This means blocking if you perform asynchronous tasks such as network operations.

It is possible to execute an `Operation` directly. In the case where you want concurrent execution of those operations you need to make them asynchronous.  It is in this situation that you would override `start()`

> If you want to implement a concurrent operation—that is, one that runs asynchronously with respect to the calling thread—you must write additional code to start the operation asynchronously. For example, you might spawn a separate thread, call an asynchronous system function, or do anything else to ensure that the start method starts the task and returns immediately and, in all likelihood, before the task is finished.
>
> Most developers should never need to implement concurrent operation objects. If you always add your operations to an operation queue, you do not need to implement concurrent operations. When you submit a nonconcurrent operation to an operation queue, the queue itself creates a thread on which to run your operation. Thus, adding a nonconcurrent operation to an operation queue still results in the asynchronous execution of your operation object code. The ability to define concurrent operations is only necessary in cases where you need to execute the operation asynchronously without adding it to an operation queue.

In summary, make sure your operations are synchronous and do not override `start` if you want to take advantage of `progress`

**Update**

While the normal advice is not to try and make asynchronous tasks synchronous, in this case it is the only thing you can do if you want to take advantage of `progress`.  The problem is that if you have an asynchronous operation, the queue cannot tell when it is actually complete.  If the queue can't tell when an operation is complete then it can't update `progress` accurately for that operation.

You do need to consider the impact on the thread pool of doing this.

The alternative is not to use the inbuilt `progress` feature and create your own property that you update from your tasks.

Comment: I'm aware operations are dispatched to a separate thread when enqueued onto an operation queue. However, if one has an operation that is _asynchronous_, i.e. overrides `isAsynchronous=true` and implements the requisite KVO notifications, it cannot participate in `progress`. This seems odd and couples operations to an`OperationQueue` (granted I only ever use them on an `OperationQueue`). Alas, I've updated my question to include a new `SyncOperation` that simply waits until my asynchronous task is complete.

Comment: From the document I quoted *The ability to define concurrent operations is only necessary in cases where you need to execute the operation asynchronously without adding it to an operation queue.* - In other words it is never necessary to have a concurrent operation on a queue.  Blocking the operation (Making it synchronous) is the correct thing to do in this case

Comment: Interesting, I have had success with asynchronous operations working correctly with an operation queue, but given both the documentation you’ve linked to and ‘progress’ not working with them, I agree blocking is the appropriate avenue to go! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Normally I would say so too, but Apple seems to indicate that `Operation`s should be synchronous. Certainly if you want to use `progress` you have to make them so. I guess it depends on the concurrency limit of your queue. If you need to dispatch a lot of concurrent operations then you will be better off tracking progress yourself.

Comment: I agree generally, and I will revise my answer to clarify that I am not suggesting that this is what you should always do.  In this specific case, however, the OP has a choice; Make their operations synchronous and take advantage of `progress` or keep them asynchronous and implement their own progress monitoring.

Answer (score 4):

You ask:

> Does this mean asynchronous operations and progress are mutually exclusive (i.e. only synchronous operations can be used with progress)? This seems like a massive limitation if this is the case.

Yes, if you implement `start`, you have to add the operation’s child `Progress` to the queue’s parent `progress` yourself. (It is a little surprising that they did not have the base operation update the progress by observing the `isFinished` KVO, but it is what it is. Or they could have used the `becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount:)`-`resignCurrent` pattern, and then this fragile behavior would not exist.)

But I would not abandon asynchronous operations solely because you want their `Progress`. By making your operation synchronous, you would unnecessarily tie up one of the very limited number of worker threads for the duration of the operation. That is the sort of decision that seems very convenient, might not introduce immediate problems, but longer-term might introduce problems that are exceedingly hard to identify when you unexpectedly exhaust your worker thread pool.

Fortunately, adding our own child `Progress` is exceedingly simple. Consider a custom operation with its own child `Progress`:

```swift
class TestOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
    let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 1)

    override func main() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [self] in
            progress.completedUnitCount = 1
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

And then, while adding them to your queue, add the operation’s `progress` as a child of the operation queue’s `Progress`:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    let queue: OperationQueue = ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        queue.progress.totalUnitCount = 10
        progressView.observedProgress = queue.progress

        for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
            queue.progress.becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount: 1)
            queue.addOperation(TestOperation())
            queue.progress.resignCurrent()
        }
    }
}
```

It is trivial to add the `Progress` of your own, custom, asynchronous, `Operation` subclasses to the operation queue’s `Progress`. Or, you might just create your own parent `Progress` and bypass the `progress` of the `OperationQueue` entirely. But either way, it is exceedingly simple and there is no point in throwing the baby (asynchronous custom `Operation` subclass) away with the bathwater.

---

If you want, you could simplify the calling point even further, e.g., define `typealias` for operations with `Progress`:

```swift
typealias ProgressOperation = Operation & ProgressReporting

extension OperationQueue {
    func addOperation(progressOperation: ProgressOperation, pendingUnitCount: Int64 = 1) {
        progress.addChild(progressOperation.progress, withPendingUnitCount: pendingUnitCount)
        addOperation(progressOperation)
    }
}

class TestOperation: AsynchronousOperation, ProgressReporting {
    let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 1)

    override func main() { ... }
}
```

And then when adding operations:

```swift
queue.progress.totalUnitCount = 10
progressView.observedProgress = queue.progress

for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
    queue.addOperation(progressOperation: TestOperation())
}
```

Comment: Ooo, I like this! I completely forgot Progress objects can have children (first time I’m using the API actually). For context, I’m building a mini Core Data synchronization framework and using an operation for each step. I already have a bunch of operation protocols for passing data been operations and an additional Progressive one should fit in nicely. I might actually make it a requirement of AsyncOperation. Also good call on the threads (granted my queue is serial), but thread explosion is dangerous.

Comment: Yup, tried this out and it works wonderfully! I ended up using the built-in protocol `ProgressReporting` instead of creating my own :)

Comment: Nice. Updated answer to include `ProgressReporting`. Thanks!